# JavaScript - fetch api data is run too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from api to pass it as array to Select's options. The problem is that data is fetched too late. My constructor():

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      optionSelected: null,
      options: []
    };
  }
```

My componentDidMount():

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/authors/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        for (var x in data) {
          this.state.options.push({"value": x, "label": data[x]})
        }
      })
  ;}
```

With code like that I get  [empty drop down, with only "select all" option available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gz7a.png).
But when I choose that "select all", drop down options are instantly populated with api data and all are selected. If I unselect all of them they remain as avaialble options. Can you please advice how can I make fetch populate options earlier then this so they were shown as select options from the very beggining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out to update options by using spread operator :

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/authors/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
           let options=[]
           for (var x in data) {
             options.push({"value": x, "label": data[x]})
            }
        

        this.setState({...this.state,options:options});
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never modify a React state via `this.state` outside the constructor! Use a `setState` function instead.

Modify your function to:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/authors/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let options = Object.assign({}, ...this.state.data);

        for (var x in data) {
          options.push({"value": x, "label": data[x]})
        }

        this.setState({ data });
      });
}
```

Comment: I tried Your way and got an error that `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): options.push is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Keep note of how to update the state in an component -
[manage component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html)

```js
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/authors/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {           
          let options = Object.keys(data).reduce((accum, elem) => {
            accum.push[{"value": elem, "label": data[elem]}];
            return accum;
          }, []);

          this.setState((state) => {
            return {
              ...state,
              options: options
            }
          });
      });
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it returned error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`.